# Вывод данных из БД для графика

Tags: json, php, javascript

Есть база данных, в которой собираются лиды(клиенты), нужно сделать график по дням за текущий месяц, т.е. сколько лидов(киентов) добавилось за месяц все это разбить по дням.

В базе есть поле datetime в формате 2014-03-14 10:35:20

Начал писать код:

```
 <?
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,datetime FROM lids WHERE month(datetime)='07' and year(datetime)='2014' ORDER BY datetime and id_klient = '39'");
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)                             
    do {
    ?>{
    "category": "<? echo $myrow['day'] ?>",
    "column-1": 10
    },
    <?
    } while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
    ?>
```

Но понял, что что-то я не то делаю, прошу помочь.

**РЕШИЛ САМ**

```
<?
                                $month = "07";
                                $year = "2014";

                                    $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
                                    for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++)
                                    {
                                        $mktime=mktime(0,0,0,$month,$i,$year);
                                        $date=date("d",$mktime);
                                        $dates_month[$i]=$date;
                                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,datetime FROM lids WHERE DAY(`datetime`) = '$date' ORDER BY datetime and id_klient = '39'");
                                        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
                                        ?>{
                                    "category": "<? echo $date ?>",
                                    "column-1": <? echo $count ?>
                                },
                                        <?
                                    }
                                ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

воспользуйтесь библиотекой gd2

вот такое сможете нарисовать

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]